# ServiceNotFoundException' 'Unable to resolve service "Router" to a factory

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework3

i'm using zend framework 3 with doctrine 2 and it giving me this error i dnt know why

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'Unable to resolve service "Router" to a factory; are you certain you
>   provided it during configuration?' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php:681
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(757):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->getFactory('Router') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(200):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Router') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(158):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Router') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(273):
>   Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap(Array) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\public\index.php(40):
>   Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array) #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 681

Comment: Please paste your `module.config.php` here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same problem while upgrading an app from zf2 to zf3.

I solved the problem by loading the module Zend\Router. There are some more modules coming with ZF3, so I ended up using this in the modules.config.php:

```
return [
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Hydrator',
    'Zend\InputFilter',
    'Zend\Paginator',
    'Zend\I18n',
    'Zend\Filter',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Zend\Navigation',
    ...
];
```

I got the modules.config.php and the new application.config.php from the [zf3 skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication).